# Rails renders view when redirected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

So I have a Rails 4 app that uses Devise for authentication. I have started writing controller tests when I noticed odd behaviour and confirmed it in firebug.

When I try to access a controller action, that has `before_action :authenticate_user!`, it returns a response with 302 Found header and a BODY for the first database entry and after that it redirects to `new_user_session_path`. Therefore if someone would just open up a console and look at it, they can see information, that's supposed to be hidden from them.

And I just don't understand how can it render a body for a user, when the user is found like `@user = current_user` and there is no `current_user`, or at least there shouldn't be.

I have looked but found nothing. Here are some additional info: Devise version 3.5.2, Rails 4.2.4

**EDIT**

Rails log when trying to access authenticated page

```
Started GET "/dashboard" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-28 11:07:27 +0100
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-28 11:07:27 +0100
Processing by Users::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered users/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (1.4ms)
  Rendered shared/_navigation.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered shared/_flashes.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 192ms (Views: 191.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

And this is what FireBug shows. I don't understand why is it different

```
GET dashboard 302 Found localhost:3000 101 B 127.0.0.1:3000 16ms
GET sign_in 200 OK localhost:3000 6,6 KB 127.0.0.1:3000
```

**EDIT 2**

So I figured out it has nothing to do with Devise. Even if I implement my own authenticate method and use that in `before_action` instead of `authenticate_user!`, it still doesn't work. The action renders the view, although, when I put `byebug` in the action, it did not break. So I'm renaming the question.

**EDIT 3**

All possibly relevant pieces of code.

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Oregano</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <%= render 'shared/navigation' %>

  <% if content_for? :welcome %>
    <div class="section welcome-section">
      <div class="container">
        <div id="flashes"><%= render 'shared/flashes' %></div>
        <%= yield :welcome %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% else %>
    <div id="page-wrapper">
      <div class="section">
        <div class="container main-content">
          <div id="flashes"><%= render 'shared/flashes' %></div>
          <div class="row">
            <%= yield :top %>
          </div>
          <div class="row bottom-index-part">
            <div class="col-md-8 index">
              <%= yield :main %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div id="showDetailsWell" class="well well-sm hidden">
                <%= yield :details %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

users/show.html.erb

```
<% content_for :top do %>
  <div class="user-header header-combo">
    <%= gravatar_image_tag current_user.email, alt: "#{current_user.name} gravatar", class: 'img-circle' %>
    <h1 class="heading"><%= current_user.name %></h1>
  </div>
<% end %>

<% content_for :main do %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <h3>My interests</h3>
      <%= render 'shared/add_tag', resource: current_user, tag_name: 'interest', label_name: 'I like to' %>
      <div class="tags-row interests-row">
        <% current_user.user_interests.each do |ui| %>
          <%= render 'shared/remove_tag', resource: ui, path: [@user, ui] unless ui.new_record? %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <h3>My places</h3>
      <%= render 'shared/add_tag', resource: current_user, tag_name: 'place', label_name: 'I live in' %>
      <div class="tags-row places-row">
        <% current_user.user_places.each do |up| %>
          <%= render 'shared/remove_tag', resource: up, path: [@user, up] unless up.new_record? %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7 about-user">
      <%= render 'about_show' %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 contact-info-user">
      <%= render 'contact_info_show' %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

UsersController#show

```
  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        @user = current_user
      end
      format.js do
        @user = User.find params[:id]
        @group = params[:group_id] ? Group.find(params[:group_id]) : nil
      end
    end
  end
```

excerpt from routes.rb

```
get 'dashboard', to: 'users#show', as: 'dashboard'
resources :users, only: [:show, :index] do
  resources :user_interests
  resources :user_places
  resources :relationships, only: [:index]
  member do
    get 'get_interests_json'
  end
  collection do
    get 'edit_about', to: 'users#edit_about'
    patch 'about', to: 'users#update_about'
    get 'edit_contact_info', to: 'users#edit_contact_info'
    patch 'contact_info', to: 'users#update_contact_info'
  end
end
```

ApplicationController

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :init_scope_hash
  before_action :authenticate_basic
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  include ApplicationHelper

  protected
  def init_scope_hash
    @scope = {}
  end
  def authenticate_basic
    if Rails.env.production?
      authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
        username == "blablabl" && password == "blablabla"
      end
    end
  end

end
```

**EDIT 4**

ApplicationHelper

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def universalise string
    res = string.gsub(/[ÁÄáäČčĎďÉéÍíĹĺĽľŇÓÔóôŔŕŠšŤťÚúÝýŽž]/, 'AAaaCcDdEeIiLlLlNOOooRrSstTUuYyZz')
    res.downcase
  end

  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you be more explicit - what's in the response? Can you provide a small example that shows the issue?

Comment: @FrederickCheung see edit

Comment: The specifics don't matter, but the response is the same as if the request was authenticated.

Comment: The firebug / console logs you've posted look fine - dashboard renders no data and the next request is for the signin page

Comment: It doesn't seem to be Devise's fault. Even if I implement my own authenticate_user! method, it still does the same

Comment: could you please show the relevant parts of the controller and the view?

Comment: @tillmo What do you mean, relevant parts? If you mean the `authenticate_user!` method, that's from Devise (although I have tried to implement my own that worked in other project, didn't work here). And if you mean a controller action, it's nothing special. Just a `respond_to` block and assigning a variable in it

Comment: I mean the controller method call for route `/dashboard`, and the view in `app/users/show.html.erb` (or `.haml` or whatever).

Comment: @tillmo I don't think it is relevant, because this happens throughout the all app, not just this one action

Comment: but something must be relevant that causes the non-standard behaviour. It is difficult to debug this without seeing any code. Note that the 302 in Firebug is no problem, it also occurs for me. However, the HTML for the 302 should be the log in page.

Comment: @tillmo Well the 302 has a body as if it was 200. I would love to provide code to debug, I just don't know which, I can't isolate it. I can show you the view if you want, but I can't see how it's going to help

Comment: what about `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`? What happens if you assign a variable in a controller action and use it in the view? If the controller action is not exectued, but the view is rendered, there should be an error, shouldn't it?

Comment: So I added anything that could be of any value. And that's what I said, I have no idea how is the variable assigned if the action is not executed.

Comment: Something in your ApplicationHelper perhaps?

Comment: don't think so, but see for yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. It was caused by *browser cache*. No `rails` error.

It was really an accident, I did some changes in a layout and loaded it in FF when signed in and then opened up a private window and observed the response, it was changed too. Then I changed the layout back and did another request, but noticed that the response did not change. When I reloaded it in my active session FF, it changed in the private window as well. So I disabled browser cache and it worked.

I still can't believe that this was it.

Answer (score 0):

use an unnamed `yield` instead of (one of) the named ones in `application.html.erb`

Comment: Thanks @tillmo, even though your answer is not the correct one :D, it set me on the path to figure it out, so have the bounty :)

Comment: oh, many thanks! Indeed, sometimes it is more like a detective story: you have to exclude one possibility after another...